# Create adds entry to table multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a model that has several `datetime` fields, all of which have the same date, but different times. So in my form for that model I ask for the date once, and then ask for times for each of the others to avoid asking for the same date over and over again.

Once my form returns the `params` hash to my controller I have a function, `add_date_to_time` that goes through each key and sets its date value to the date entered earlier in the form. It is then supposed to delete the date keys from the hash and won't - any input as far as why that is happening would be appreciated.

There are two big problems I am running into:

1) The most important one - It is creating an entry 7 times. So if I add a show, that show gets added to the database 7 times instead of one. Also, after I hit submit on the form when I go back to the shows index it says no data received. If I reload it the page appears properly.

2) The smaller problem - the code to permit all of the different keys in the hash is hideous. Is there a better way to permit that many keys at once?

My classes:

Model for `Show`

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :date
end
```

Controller for `Show`

```
class ShowsController < ApplicationController
  helper ShowsHelper

  def index
    @shows = Show.all
  end

  def new
    @show = Show.new
  end

  def create
    add_date_to_times
    if Show.create permit_params
      redirect_to 'shows', alert: 'Show successfully created'
    else
      redirect_to 'shows'
    end
  end

  private
  def permit_params
    params.require(:show).permit(:artist, :'date(1i)', :'date(2i)', :'date(3i)', :'doors_open(1i)', :'doors_open(2i)', :'doors_open(3i)',
                                 'doors_open(4i)', :'doors_open(5i)', :'dinner_starts(1i)', :'dinner_starts(2i)',
        'dinner_starts(3i)', :'dinner_starts(4i)', :'dinner_starts(5i)', :'dinner_ends(1i)', :'dinner_ends(2i)',
                                 'dinner_ends(3i)', :'dinner_ends(4i)', :'dinner_ends(5i)', :'show_starts(1i)', :'show_starts(2i)',
                                 'show_starts(3i)', :'show_starts(4i)', :'show_starts(5i)', :'show_ends(1i)', :'show_ends(2i)',
                                 'show_ends(3i)', :'show_ends(4i)', :'show_ends(5i)')
  end

  private
  def add_date_to_times
    append_date_to_time 'doors_open'
    append_date_to_time 'dinner_starts'
    append_date_to_time 'dinner_ends'
    append_date_to_time 'show_starts'
    append_date_to_time 'show_ends'
    params.delete 'date(3i)'
    params.delete 'date(2i)'
    params.delete 'date(1i)'
    #%w(1 2 3).map { |e| params.delete("date(#{e}i)")}
  end

  def append_date_to_time(attribute)
    %w(1 2 3).map { |e| params[:show]["#{attribute}(#{e}i)"] = params[:show]["date(#{e}i)"] }
  end
end
```

New form for `Show`

```
=form_for @show, html: {role: "form"} do |f|
  .form-group
    =f.label :artist
    =f.text_field :artist, class: "form-control"
  .form-group
    =f.label :date
    =f.date_select :date, order: [:day, :month, :year], class: "form-control"
  .form-group
    =f.label :doors_open
    =f.time_select :doors_open, class: "form-control"
  .form-group
    =f.label :dinner_starts
    =f.time_select :dinner_starts, class: "form-control"
  .form-group
    =f.label :dinner_ends
    =f.time_select :dinner_ends, class: "form-control"
  .form-group
    =f.label :show_starts
    =f.time_select :show_starts, class: "form-control"
  .form-group
    =f.label :show_ends
    =f.time_select :show_ends, class: "form-control"
  .form-group
    =f.submit "Create Show", class: "btn btn-default"
```

My `schema.rb`

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150213030338) do

  create_table "shows", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "artist"
    t.datetime "doors_open"
    t.datetime "dinner_starts"
    t.datetime "dinner_ends"
    t.datetime "show_starts"
    t.datetime "show_ends"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
  end

end
```

Comment: Hi Thom! how does look your schema for the showcontroller

Comment: thnks @ThomYorkkke, Please walk me throuht your Model. I don't understand why there is so many 'door_opens(...). Would you mean that a Show has many Artist . and each Shows has a :start_time and :end_time && each Shows has a dinner_start_time and dinner_end_time.

Comment: So the door to the show opens at a certain time, then the dinner starts, then the dinner ends, then the show starts then the show ends. A show also has only one artist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I prefer to use [nested_forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1). Cause a Show has an Artist (Show => (1)(Artist) and if you want to implement an Artist into the Shows' form you should use a nested_form approach

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :show
end
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :artist

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :artist
end
```

for the controller Show

```
  def new
    @show = Show.new
    @artist = @show.build_artist
  end
  def show_params
    params.require(:show).permit(:show_date, :doors_open, :doors_end, :show_start, :show_ends, :dinner_opens, :dinner_ends, 
        :artist_attributes => [:id, :name])
  end
```

and for the Shows/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@show) do |f| %>
  <% if @show.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@show.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this show from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @show.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :artist do |artist_builder| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= artist_builder.label :name %>
    <%= artist_builder.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :show_date %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :show_date %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :doors_open %><br>
    <%= f.time_select :doors_open %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :doors_end %><br>
    <%= f.time_select :doors_end %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :show_start %><br>
    <%= f.time_select :show_start %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :show_ends %><br>
    <%= f.time_select :show_ends %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :dinner_opens %><br>
    <%= f.time_select :dinner_opens %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :dinner_ends %><br>
    <%= f.time_select :dinner_ends %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You could also create a model Door and Dinner and apply a nested form. But let's keep it simple.

Also for the migration use `time` instead of `datetime`

```
  def change
    create_table :shows do |t|
      t.datetime :show_date
      t.time :doors_open
      t.time :doors_end
      t.time :show_start
      t.time :show_ends
      t.time :dinner_opens
      t.time :dinner_ends

      t.timestamps
    end
```

hope it helps

Comment: That was reallly helpful. Thanks a lot! You were spot on about just making the other things times instead of datetimes.